# How to select a Tab on Outlook 2010 Ribbon

Tags: vba, outlook

I have programmed a rule calling a VBA macro that automatically forwards all email to an offsite account. Sometimes the rule fails with an Outlook (not VBA) error message and the rule becomes inactive until I reactivate it (by going through all the choices and hitting apply) then all is fine again (until the next time.)

I would like to have a macro that runs at Outlook Start-up that does one thing - select the Manage Rules & Alerts drop-down menu item under the Rules tab on the Ribbon. It would then open and would assure me the rule is activated and working.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to run commands and ribbon controls programmatically you can use the Outlook object model. The Store class provides the [GetRules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860628(v=office.15).aspx) method which returns a [Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869469.aspx) collection object that contains the Rule objects defined for the current session. You can use the [Enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868097.aspx) property of the Rule class which returns a boolean value that determines if the rule is to be applied. Here is what MSDN states:

> Setting the Enabled property of a rule does not guarantee that the rule will be enabled. The rule is enabled only after Rules.Save executes successfully.
>
> Using Rule.Enabled and Rules.Save applies the rule consistently and persists the rules beyond the current session. Enabling a rule (that has been saved successfully) ensures that the rule will be applied. If it is a local client rule, the rule will be applied when Outlook is running, and if the rule is a server-based rule, it will be applied regardless of whether Outlook is running. If you do not enable the rule, then the rule is defined, but it will not be applied. However, you can use Rule.Execute to apply a rule as an one-off operation regardless of whether the rule is enabled.

You may consider handling the [Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired when Outlook is starting, but after all add-in programs have been loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As a newbie Outlook VBA coder I have no idea even how to begin what you suggest. Could you post some code that might do what I needed as I listed above? Thanks again.

Comment: Take a look at the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) to begin.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can determine, in Outlook, selecting and activating a tab on the Ribbon is not possible programmatically.

My solution was to create a Userform that is activated in the Application_Start() routine. It gets focus on startup and acts as a reminder to do what I need to do.

For knowledge sake, I would be happy to view any other potential solutions to the original issue.